# Printing Issue of Greek Characters in Jupyter Notebook with Wolfram Engine Kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, wolfram-language

I use Jupyter Notebook with the Wolfram Engine, and I write the command:

```
Print["Συνάρτηση Green"]
```

However, instead of printing:

```
Συνάρτηση Green
```

it prints:

```
[CapitalSigma][Upsilon][Nu]:03ac[Rho][Tau][Eta][Sigma][Eta] Green
```

Why is that?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Hello, could you please add a bit of information about the research you have already done to answer this question yourself? It helps people who might answer this question to understand exactly what sort of answer would be most helpful.

Comment: @morric , I haven't been able to find anything. I've searched quite a bit so far. I didn't come here and immediately say, "Solve my problem".